# How can I print A to Z in C# (string)

Tags: c#, arrays, string

In C#

```
string[]a={"a","b","c",.......,"x","y","z"}
```

how can I print like this `「"a","b","c",.......,"x","y","z"」`with「，」？

I use

```
for (int I = 0; I <= 25; I++)
{
    Console.write(Convert.ToChar(65 + I)).toString());
}
```

it does not  worked,
can anybody tell me? thanks a lot

Comment: "*it does not worked*" - is not a technical description of a problem, please describe what you expect, and what in turns happens

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/am4kKx

Comment: Your code can't even compile. It's `.Write` not `.write` and you have too many right brackets. Remove one after `65 + i`.

Comment: Also, why loop from 0 to 25 and then add 65 to `I` on each iteration when you can just loop from 65 to 90?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I recommend you to read "[How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going by your ***exact*** example *output*

```
var chars = Enumerable.Range(0, 26)
    .Select(x => $"\"{(char)('a' + x)}\"");
    
Console.WriteLine($"「{string.Join(",", chars)}」");

// or if you like for loops, and don't mind a few more allocations

var strings = new string[26];
for (var i = 0; i < 26; i++)
    strings[i] = $"\"{(char)('a' + i)}\"";
Console.WriteLine($"「{string.Join(",", strings)}」");


// or if you like everything on one line, 
// Because... well... it will look more awesome at code club.
// Courtesy of Jerry

Console.WriteLine($"「{string.Join(',', Enumerable.Range('a', 26).Select(x => $"\"{(char) x}\""))}」");
```

**Output**

```
「"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"」
```

[**Full Demo Here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CfuPvX)

Comment: Much tidier than mine - https://dotnetfiddle.net/xhiGAT

Comment: Why not just make it a one liner? lol `Console.WriteLine($"「{string.Join(',', Enumerable.Range('a', 26).Select(x => $"\"{(char)x}\""))}」");

Comment: @Jerry, you are evil... but i like it

Comment: I have to vote you up, it never occurred to me that 'a' could just represent the value you are starting from.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (char ch = 'a'; ch <= 'z'; ch++)
{//Printing all alphabets with tab
Console.Write(ch+"\t");}
```